# Issue with log file name in EntLib5

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

I have Windows Forms application which writes log on a daily basis with this format for filename

> yyyy-mm-dd-appName.log

The settings are what comes out of the box from EntLib. I have only one trace listener.
The issue is if the user running the app opens the .log file, say in notepad or some other editor and the app is run again, the file name has a GUID like so

> 8989dsf908dsfds9900.log

I guess this is a temporary name that EntLib uses as the file is being used by both the app and notepad. When the user closes the file in notepad the file name still remains the GUID.
so in the log folder there are bunch of files with these GUIDs.

Can something be done to counter this?
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

As **Randy Levy** said in this [link](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/400468):
This is caused by file locking in System.Diagnostics.  The reason why you get multiple files is that when a user open the log file, this cause the file locks exclusively. Also Each trace listener attempt to locks (or will attempt to lock) the same file exclusively during the logging process and when it fails to obtain the lock it will create a new file prepended with a GUID.